# What is a good database design approach for my Online Quiz Android Application?

Tags: php, android, mysql, rdbms, erd

I have been working on an Android Online Quiz Application with PHP & MySQL. I know what attributes I need however when designing the relationship it becomes complex and confusing when I analysed it. I do not know if this would be a good database design before I write in MySQL and implement it in my project. See my ERD Below:

[image]

As the design above, I am trying to design that will also work for creating charts with any android chart generation library. I am not sure about this design and I am thinking that I might struggle ending up to redone my database design. Any suggestions for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you will get better answer for your question here : http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this is a good scenario to use xml/json/blobs in the db

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Is it? Would it be easier for me to create charts with this design?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been asked a [second time on the correct SE site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/126854/15427) see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/201151)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, this can be built in a better way with JSON documents of a NoSQL database like MongoDB, which allows you to do the following:

- Schema less : MongoDB is document database in which one collection
  holds different different documents.
- Structure of a single object
  is clear.
- No complex joins.
- Deep query-ability.
- Tuning.
- Ease of
  scale-out: MongoDB is easy to scale.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/index.htm

Try out mLab as it provide MongoDb-as-a-service and can be easily connected to a web app deployed using Heroku. 
https://mlab.com/